# How to upload bulk data to Google Servers using Google App Engine running on Java?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am not able to figure out how to upload bulk data to the Google's servers bypassing the 10mb upload limit and 30 sec session timeout. I want to design an application that takes my standard SQL data and pushes it to the Google's servers.

I might sound naive but your help is most valuable for my project.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's not currently a native Java bulkloader, so what you need to do is use the Python one. The process goes like this:

First, you'll need to download the [Python SDK](http://code.google.com/appengine/downloads.html#Google_App_Engine_SDK_for_Python) and extract it. Then, create an empty directory, and in it create a file called app.yaml, containing the following:

```
application: yourappid
version: bulkload
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /remote_api
  script: $PYTHON_LIB/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/handler.py
  login: admin
```

Now, run "appcfg.py update yourdir" from the Python SDK, and enter your credentials when prompted. appcfg will upload a new version of your app, which will run side-by-side with your main version, and allow you to bulkload.

Now, to do the actual bulkloading, you need to use the Python Bulkloader. Follow the instructions [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html#Creating_Loader_Classes). You'll need to know a (very) little bit of Python, but it's mostly copy-and-paste. When you're done, you can run the bulkloader as described in the article, but add the "-s bulkload.latest.yourapp.appspot.com" argument to the command line, like this:

```
appcfg.py upload_data --config_file=album_loader.py --filename=album_data.csv --kind=Album -s bulkload.latest.yourapp.appspot.com <app-directory>
```

Finally, to load data directly from an SQL database instead of from a CSV file, follow the instructions in my blog post [here](http://blog.notdot.net/2009/9/Advanced-Bulk-Loading-part-3-Alternate-datasources).

Comment: This solution have been depreciated. New instructions are [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html)

Comment: Also, the `appcfg.py update yourdir` step won't work if you have 2-step verification setup on your google account. I just switched it off as the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

I wanna do the same thing also. So, here's my naivest concept to achieve the goal.

### Web Server Preparation

1. **Create a servlet** that will receive the uploaded data (e.g. for data type
   *XML*, *JSON*)

   *(optional)* store it as Blobstore
2. **Parse** the data using JAXB/JSoup and/or GSON
3. Dynamically **interpret** the data structure
4. **Store** it using Datastore/

### Client Uploader Preparation

1. Using a local computer, **create** a *Java/C++/PHP* script that generates *XML/JSON* files and store it locally
2. **Create** a *shell script* (linux) or *batch file* (windows) to programatically upload the files using **[cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)**.

Please drop a comment to this one if you have better idea guys.